# Sync data between mobile apps and website

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm developing a mobile app based on website. On this website, there are notifications. I was able to get them thanks to a post request and display them in the mobile app. For the moment the only way to mark a notification as viewed is via the website but I'd also like to do that on the mobile app (I mean like Facebook : you read a notification on the app and you don't have to read it again on the website). The only problem is I have no idea how I can do that.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I would suggest you to use library for notifications in Angular2. 
[Angular2-notifications](https://github.com/flauc/angular2-notifications)

Comment: When you read it on the  app, send a POST to the website API to indicate the item is read. Use the http library or similar.

Comment: That's what I did. Thanks @jalal